# How to connect WiFi to non-W RPi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, connection, ethernet, arduino-esp8266

I have a Raspberry Pi Zero, that has not built-in WiFi module. Can I buy a WiFi module to connect it to Internet? For example, Arduino's ESP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can buy a WiFi module that connects via USB, e.g. this one from [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B014HTNO52) (no affiliation).

Note you'll need a USB-to-microUSB adapter to connect to to the Zero as well.

Good luck!